# Why is not needed to handle Exception throw by Callable interface

Tags: java, exception, callable

I have a code sniping like this:

```
import java.util.concurrent.Callable;
import java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException;
import java.util.concurrent.ExecutorService;
import java.util.concurrent.Executors;

public class UserManagementApplication {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException, ExecutionException {
        ExecutorService es = Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor();
        MyCallable callable = new MyCallable(10);
        MyThread thread = new MyThread(10);
        System.out.println(es.submit(callable).get());
        System.out.println(es.submit(thread).get());
        es.shutdown();
    }
}

class MyCallable implements Callable<Integer> {
    private Integer i;

    public MyCallable(Integer i) {
        this.i = i;
    }

    @Override
    public Integer call() throws Exception {
        return --i;
    }
}

class MyThread extends Thread {
    private int i;

    MyThread(int i) {
        this.i = i;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        i++;
    }
}
```

I don't understand why the compiler does not complain in main because **MyCallable** has a method that is declared as throws Exception.
I am sure that I am missing something obvious here but simply I can't see it right now.
Thanks

Comment: A bit simplified, but: You only need to deal with exceptions if you are actually calling the method. Try adding `callable.call()` to your `main` method.

Comment: Yes, there is the error that I was looking for :))

Comment: Aside: you don't actually have to have `throw Exception` on your `call()` if you don't throw a checked exception.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The exception is thrown in a seperate thread so you don't need to handle it directly in the main thread. If `call()` throws an exception the seperated thread will let you know over the `ExecutionException`.

You need to understand that if a thread terminates due to an error it does not terminate the main thread, or any other thread, because they are seperated threads. Handling exceptions is only relevant when the exception is throwable within the thread the code is running in itself.

Comment: Yes, that makes sense. One more question, ExecutionException inherit from Exception. Call method definition declares a throws Exception. How will it be possible in this separated thread to throw an Exception if ExecutionException is a subclass of Exception? I don't know how clear I am here.

Comment: @Adrian When the thread terminates the ```ExecutorService``` will notice/handle that for you. The exception from the ```call()``` method is not passed to the main thread. The call happens, something goes wrong, the seperated thread terminates, the service notices that the thread terminated and throws an ```ExecutionException```.